# WinUI 3 Desktop XAML Databinding - WinRT originate error - 0x8001010E when the Property is changed

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

I am following the BookStore data binding example, documented at [XAML controls; bind to a C++/WinRT property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-property#add-a-property-of-type-bookstoreviewmodel-to-mainpage), up to and including the "Bind the button to the Title property" section.

My starting point is a new "Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)" project in Visual Studio.

[EDIT] Starting from a "Blank App (C++/WinRT)" project, which is for UWP apps, works perfectly. The problem persists with "WinUI 3 in Desktop" projects.

The initial data binding works and the button content `L"Atticus"` is read from the BookSku title property. However calling `MainViewModel().BookSku().Title(L"To Kill a Mockingbird");` in the click handler, as directed in article, throws the exception

`Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC801B4ED9 (KernelBase.dll) in BookStore.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x8001010E : 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.'.`

Stepping through the code, the call

`m_propertyChanged(*this, Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"Title" });`

in `void BookSku::Title(hstring const& value)` is where the exception is thrown from within.

I can change the button content manually, not through the binding property.

The first example in the [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) article describes a very similar, though slightly less complicated, data binding scenario. It throws the same exception.

I am using latest Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT version 2.0.210825.3 and Windows App SDK version 0.8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue [#4547](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4547) was the key to figuring out the solution. You need to use the `Microsoft` namespace, not `Windows`. For documentation purposes this is what the `BookSku.idl` file should look like:

```
// BookSku.idl
namespace Bookstore
{
    runtimeclass BookSku : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        BookSku(String title);
        String Title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

The problem is you update the property in the no-uithread, so it will throw the above exception, you could use the following to go back to ui-thread before updating the property.

```
co_await winrt::resume_foreground(Dispatcher(), CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal);
```

For more detail please refer to [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/resume-foreground).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. `Dispatcher()` is returning a unintialised object so `resume_forground` is throwing an "Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000". I realised it could be important to point out that this is a "WinUI 3 in Desktop" project rather than UWP, so I've added that detail to the question.

Also, if it's important, I can change the button content manually, not through the binding property. So does that mean I am already on the correct thread without `resume_forground`? I've added that note to the question too.

Comment: As a follow-up. I tried following the guides starting from a "Blank App (C++/WinRT)" project, which is for UWP apps. With that everything works perfectly.

Comment: Last comment, I've figured it out, it was related to a namespace difference.